# Casting in this case?

Tags: java

```
public void writeFile()
    {
         Collections.sort(snackAL);
            pw = new PrintWriter("snacksbyprice.txt");
            for (Snack snack : snackAL) {
                pw.println(snack);
            }
            pw.close();
            Collections.sort(snackAL, new NameComparator());
            for (Snack snack : snackAL) {
                System.out.println(snack);
            }
            ArrayList<Pastry> pastryAL = new ArrayList<Pastry>();
            for (Snack snack : snackAL) {
                if (snack instanceof Pastry) {
                    pastryAL.add(snack);
                }
            }
            Collections.sort(pastryAL, new PremiumNameComparator());
            pw = new PrintWriter("pastriesbypremium.csv");
            for (Snack pastry : pastryAL) {
                pw.println(pastry.getName() + ", " + pastry.getPrice() + ", " + ((Pastry) pastry).isPremium());
            }
            pw.close();
        }
```

I have this code but I keep getting an error at the pastryAL.add(snack). I was told that casting would fix it but I have no idea how to cast it in this case. I tried to do ((Pastry) Pastry) but it didn't work. The error is: The method add(Pastry) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments(Snack)

Comment: You would not write `(Pastry) Pastry`, since `Pastry` is not an expression, it is a class name. You need to cast `snack` in the `add` call, so `pastryAL.add((Pastry) snack);`.

Comment: @kaya3 i have no idea how to upvote a comment but thank you, that helped me out alot.